# SSRS Parameter needs a MulitSelect with Null

Tags: sql, reporting-services

At this point I'm not 100% sure what I need to be asking, but here's the best I'm thinking of at the moment.

I have an SSRS Parameter that is generated from a query. It will populate with a list similar to

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

I then need to use this parameter (call it `@Fruit`) in the where statement of another query. Here's the catch, I also may need to search for `Null`.

To add a placeholder for `Null` in `@Fruit` I'm using

```
Select fruit
From fruitTable
Union All
Select Null
```

This doesn't let the list populate in SSRS though because I'm doing multi-select and `Null` isn't allowed in a multi-select.

So two fold question, how do I allow for `Null` or a placeholder ideally (more user friendly like `Not Entered`) in the Parameter list population and secondly how do I then query against that in the main query?

**Additional Info**

Example table

```
FruitTable
-----------
Fruit
=====
Apple
Orange
Banana

PeopleTable
---------------------
Name | FavoriteFruit
==== | ==============
Bob  | Apple
John | Orange
Bill | Null
```

Example Queries

```
Select Name, FavoriteFruit
From PeopleTable
Where FavoriteFruit in (@Fruit)

In this example @Fruit would be ('Apple','Orange',Null) ideally
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Or is null` is a good place to start:

```
Select Name, FavoriteFruit
From PeopleTable
Where FavoriteFruit in (@Fruit)
or FavoriteFruit  is null
```

of course, you could add 'None' as an option:

```
Select Name, FavoriteFruit
From PeopleTable
Where FavoriteFruit in (@Fruit)
or (FavoriteFruit is null and 'None' in (@Fruit))
```

Comment: What if I don't want to get Null sometimes? It's possible the users would select only real values, or they could select only null, or any combination.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you a million times over. I've been fighting this all day!